# What does '(text: string): Observable<Response>=>{}' mean

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I saw syntax something like this but it didn't make sense.

```
public request= (text: string): Observable<Response> => {
    const url = `https://my.api.com/search?q=${text}`;
    return this.http
        .get(url)
        .map(data => data.json());
};
```

request is name of the function,

{} is actual function, but what is:

```
(text: string): Observable<Response>
```

It supposed to be type of function right?

What is the return type of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more like

```
function(text: string): Observable<Response> {
}
```

Comment: so it takes string, and returns observable. Thanks!